# Clarifying on the use of と

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I came over this sentence during my study.

> ちらっと見ると、彼女も寒さで震えている

I understand the latter half of the sentence, in the sense that "the girl was shivering from the cold".
However, I have no idea what does the two と play at the first half of the sentence. My closest guess is that the と from "見ると" is a conditional. But in this case, the conditional does not make sense as "when he glanced at the girl? , she was shivering from the cold. What confused me is that he does not necessarily have to look at the girl to have her shiver from the cold.

Edit: ちらっと , is the と here part of an entire word? or is it acting as a particle

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned ちらっと is just one word.

As for your second question, this is from 明鏡国語辞典: (I believe this def. best fits here)

> ある事柄の生起や認識のきっかけを表す。「トンネルを抜けると海だ」「家に帰ると食事の支度ができていた」「そんなことを言われると照れるな」
>
> ちらっと見ると、彼女も寒さで震えている
>
> As I look at her, I realize/see that she is shivering as well.